# Check if user agreed to terms , set cookie

Tags: drupal, forms, cookies, confirmation

I'm a Drupal nub. I would like to check on every page if user (anonymouse) agreed to somekind of terms. I suppose i should write small custom module ?

Where will this condition be written
 if(!$_COOKIE('confirm')){
    //jQuery show confirmation form 
    //Set cookie for 1hour
 }
maybee in page.tpl.php ? Please, give me some tips ..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the info for a long time, you should use `$_SESSION` variable. Then in preprocess page you could check if the user has accepted and set a variable that you can use in your `page.tpl.php`.

Comment: I have many .tpl.php pages and nodes. Where should be the condition written, in every .tpl.php ? 

Thank you for answering ..

Comment: i should write themeName_preprocess function, right ? and inside should be if statement ...

Answer (score 0):

[user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_save/6) accepts an array argument which you can put custom data into. This will then be loaded with your $user object and you can use in any template file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these modules:

http://drupal.org/project/legal

http://drupal.org/project/terms_of_use

Answer (score 0):

The Legal and TOS modules are good if you need a login. If working with anonymous users, however, you'll need to use the rules module with https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_session_vars.